Google doesn't index a category of pages on a Wordpress website
it's been probably a month from when we published new pages to improve the SEO of our website : o-matic.ch.
Google doesn't index those pages from the beginning and doesn't crawled them.
Our website is a wordpress and the pages are a category of archive.
The pages are the following :

https://o-matic.ch/service/
https://o-matic.ch/service/applications-mobiles/
https://o-matic.ch/service/consulting/
https://o-matic.ch/service/motion-illustrations/
https://o-matic.ch/service/sites-applications-web/
https://o-matic.ch/service/ux-ui/

We tried all we could find :

Reupload the sitemap
Ask to index (every day or 2/3 daysince the beginning)
Test the page then ask to index
Add internal link on our homepage (from the beginning) and other pages which are all previously indexed

Our last idea is to add linkrel="canonical" href="URL" on our pages but we don't know if it could help.
Have you another idea ?

Not a programming question. You might find [webmasters.se] is a better place to ask, but check their help centre before posting.

Google doesn't guarantee to index a page within a certain timescale, or at all. A month is quite a short time to expect Google to index new content.
